Don't want bibliographic entries to be numbered
This is my MWE
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{} Allinger, N. L., Zhou, X., and Bergsma, J. 1994. J. Mol. Struct. (Theochem.), 312, 69.
\bibitem{} Barrows, S. E., Storer, J. W., Cramer, C. J., French, A. D., and Truhlar, D. G. 1998. J. Comput. Chem., 19, 1111.
\bibitem{} Bays, J. P. 1992. J. Chem. Edu., 69, 209.
\bibitem{} Beachy, M. D., Chasman, D., Murphy, R. B., Halgren, T. A., and Friesner, R. A. 1997. J. Am. Chem. Soc., 119, 5908.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

As you can see, there's a square-bracketed number brefore each item in bibliography.
I'd need to compile the same bibliography, but without these numbers.
From the various research on this site, the most often appeared tip is \usepackage{natbib}.
However, this package gives the following error:

! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
citations.

Since I compile PDF files directly from Notepad++ using the command
NPP_SAVE
Current directory: $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
"miktex_to_latex.bat"  "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "tesi" "tesi.pdf"

with miktex_to_latex.bat content is
:: Called from Notepad++ Run  
:: [path_to_bat_file] "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"  

:: Change Drive and  to File Directory  
%~d1  
cd %1

:: Run Cleanup  
call:cleanup  

:: Run pdflatex -&gt; bibtex -&gt; pdflatex -&gt; pdflatex  
pdflatex %2  
bibtex  %2  
:: If you are using multibib the following will run bibtex on all aux files  
:: FOR /R . %%G IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %%G  
pdflatex %2  
pdflatex %2  

:: Run Cleanup  
call:cleanup  

:: Open PDF  
START "" "C:\Users\Utente-XB\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %3 -reuse-instance  

:: Cleanup Function  
:cleanup  
del *.dvi
del *.out
:: del *.log 
:: del *.aux  
:: del *.bbl    
:: del *.blg  
:: del *.brf  

goto:eof

I'd need to use thebibliography environment or, alternatively, a command that allows me to use biblatex from Notepad++

Some of your formatting objectives for your document aren't entirely clear. Do you not intend to have citation call-outs in your document, to reference entries in the bibliography. If you do plan to have citation call-outs, should they be of the numeric type, the author-year type, or maybe of still another type? Answers to these questions will determine how you should format the mandatory and optional arguments of each \bibitem instruction. Please advise.

My idea is to get the exact same bibliography without [1], [2], [3], [4],...,[n] before the content. No specific style required.

So, no citation call-outs in the body of the document? Please confirm.

Yes,  no citation call-outs in the body of the document.

why do you use the thebibliography environment if you don't want to cite? A simple list would work too. Beside this you can use \makeatletter\def\@biblabel#1{\phantom{9}}\makeatother , but you should add arguments in the \bibitem or you will get warnings in the log due to the empty keys.

Since you don't plan to have any citation call-outs in the body of the document, I suggest you (a) load the natbib package with the option authoryear and (b) change each instance of
\bibitem{}

to something like
\bibitem[A(3001)]{a}

Feel free to replace both the optional argument (A(3001)) and the required argument (a) with suitable alternatives.
Actually, if you want to avoid getting multiple, though ultimately harmless, warning messages of the form "Package natbib Warning: Citation a' multiply defined", I suggest you use a, b, c, ... for the mandatory arguments of the \bibitem` instructions. Just make sure that the mandatory arguments you employ are unique.
Incidentally, there's no need for a \bibliographystyle instruction since you're building the bibliography entirely by hand and thus don't have a need for BibTeX either. (BibTeX uses the argument of \bibliographystyle to determine how the bibliographic entries should be formatted.)

If you don't want hanging indentation of the formatted bibliographic entries, I suggest you uncomment the line
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

in the code shown below.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} 
%\setlength\bibhang{0pt} %% optional, to suppress hanging indentation

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[A(3001)]{a} Allinger, N. L., Zhou, X., and Bergsma, J. 1994. J. Mol. Struct. (Theochem.), 312, 69.

\bibitem[A(3001)]{b} Barrows, S. E., Storer, J. W., Cramer, C. J., French, A. D., and Truhlar, D. G. 1998. J. Comput. Chem., 19, 1111.

\bibitem[A(3001)]{c} Bays, J. P. 1992. J. Chem. Edu., 69, 209.

\bibitem[A(3001)]{d} Beachy, M. D., Chasman, D., Murphy, R. B., Halgren, T. A., and Friesner, R. A. 1997. J. Am. Chem. Soc., 119, 5908.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


Thanks you very much!
